# Why are my icons showing duplicates of image?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styling

I am trying to create social icons at the bottom of my page but it is showing multiples of the same image.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="social">
    <span *ngFor="let socialLink of footerContent.socialLinks">
      <a mat-flat-button class="{{socialLink.socialMediaService}}-icon" href={{socialLink.url}} title={{socialLink.socialMediaService}} target={{socialLink.linktarget}}>
        <mat-icon></mat-icon>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
```

This is what the image looks like

[image]

**How can I style it so that it only shows one perfectly fit image per icon?**

Comment: I almost guarantee @MistaPrime is correct.Set background to non-repeating

Answer (score 2):

It would be hard to give precise solution without a link to your site.
But from the picture it seems the image duplicates as it is set as a background, maybe the box is too big hence the background repeats.
Perhaps this CSS can help:

```
.social a {
  backgrouind-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Or this one:

```
.social a {
  max-width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found a solution, I got rid of <mat-icon></mat-icon> and put a display property in and styled the widths and heights accordingly to the SVG icon